# how to combine sql tables into non repetitive inputs

Tags: postgresql, view

I want to get repetitive titles to have name, name and not be repeated in another Colum.

#CODE

```
create or replace view Master_view as
select books.title, books.isbn as book_id, authors.name, authors.e_mail as author_id
from book_author join books on book_author.book_id = books.id
join authors on book_author.author_id = authors.id;
```

#OUTPUT

```
               title               | book_id |           name            |           author_id            
-----------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+--------------------------------
 The Pragmatic Programmer          |  999999 | Andrew Hunt               | andyhunt@pragprogrammers.com
 The Pragmatic Programmer          |  999999 | Dave Thomas               | davethomas@pragprogrammers.com
 Pragmatic Thinking and Learning   |  999998 | Andrew Hunt               | andyhunt@pragprogrammers.com
 Pragmatic Unit Testing            |  999997 | Andrew Hunt               | andyhunt@pragprogrammers.com
 Pragmatic Unit Testing            |  999997 | Dave Thomas               | davethomas@pragprogrammers.com
 Agile Web Development with Rails  |  999996 | Dave Thomas               | davethomas@pragprogrammers.com
 Agile Web Development with Rails  |  999996 | Sam Ruby                  | samruby@pragprogrammers.com
 Agile Web Development with Rails  |  999996 | David Heinemeier Hansson  | dhh@railsrules.co
(8 rows)
```

Comment: Can you explain more ?

Comment: @YJR I want to have one row of items for example (The Pragmatic Programmer | Andrew Hunt, Dave Thomas | andyhunt@pragprogrammers.com, davethomas@pragprogrammers.com) instead of having two rows for one title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create or replace view Master_view as
select books.title, books.isbn as book_id, array_agg(authors.name), array_agg(authors.e_mail) as author_id
from book_author join books on book_author.book_id = books.id
join authors on book_author.author_id = authors.id group by (books.title, books.isbn);
```

This will give you the expected results.You have to group the rows using isbn and title of the book.